# Showing $d(x,y) = \min\{|x-y|, 1\}$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ be a metric space on $\mathbb{R}$ with metric $d(x,y) = \min\{|x-y|, 1\}$. Prove that $d$ is indeed a metric.

I can prove the first two conditions for a metric, but I am stuck on showing the triangle inequality for this one. I know I would have to split it into cases, e.g. $|x-y| < 1$, but then there are also cases for the other parts of the triangle inequality. For example: we need to show $d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y)$, under the assumption of $|x-y| < 1$, we want to show:
$$|x-y| \le \min\{|x-z|, 1\} + \min\{|z-y|, 1\}$$.
Now assume that $|x-z|<1$ and $|z-y|<1$. Then, we know that 
$$|x-y| \le |x-z|+|z-y| $$
is certainly true due to the triangle inequality on $\mathbb{R}$. Now what if say $|z-y| >1$, we would need to show 
$$|x-y| \le |x-z| + 1 $$
is true. But how? Similar for the other cases, I am not sure on how to show they are true.

Comment: You have $|x - y| < 1$ by your assumption, so you certainly have $|x - y| \le |x - z| + 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $|x - y| \geq 1$. If $z$ is between the two points, then $|x - z| + |z -y|$ must be as great as $d(x, y) = 1$ under this metric. If $z$ is not between the two points, then  $z$ has a distance of at least 1 from either $x$ or $y$. In any of these cases, the triangle inequality holds.